# Realloc array of Strings in C? segmentation error

Tags: c, arrays, string, realloc

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void sortString(const char* input, char* output);
int cmpstr(void const *a,void const *b);
int readAllWords(FILE* f, char*** res, int * num_read);
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
   char **wordList;
   FILE* fid;
   int numWords;
   fid = fopen(argv[1],"r");
  readAllWords(fid, &wordList,&numWords);
}

int readAllWords(FILE* f, char*** res, int * num_read)
{
    char buffer[128];
    *num_read = 0;
    int size;
    while(fgets(buffer,128,f))
    {
       *num_read = *num_read +1;
       size = strlen(buffer);
       res = (char***)malloc(sizeof(char**));
       *res = (char **)realloc(*res,sizeof(char*)*(*num_read));
       (*res)[(*num_read)-1] = (char *)realloc((*res)[(*num_read)-1],sizeof(char)*size);
        strcpy((*res)[(*num_read)-1],buffer);
      printf("%s\n",(*res)[(*num_read)-1]);
    }
    printf("%s\n",(*res)[0]);

}
```

The values are storing and it prints out inside the while loop. But after the while loop, it cannot print out the strings.

The File is given in the main function. Do not understand why realloc is causing the loss of data?

Comment: `res = (char***)malloc(sizeof(char**));` should be an alert as to the fact that you are doing it wrong.

Comment: [Do **NOT** cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)!

Comment: It would help to know how you're calling this function.

Comment: Looks like you aren't allocating an extra spot for the \0 in the realloc, but I agree with @H2CO3, `(char***)` is a sign that you need to refactor...

Comment: The thing is that I cannot change the function parameters so what is the proper way to initialize an array of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that the code doesn't initialize `res` in `main()`, so you attempt to `realloc()` an indeterminate value.  Either NULL or a value previously returned by `malloc()` or `realloc()` (or `calloc()`) would be OK, but since you pass an indeterminate value, you are invoking undefined behaviour, and a crash is a valid response to doing that.

However, there's a lot of other code in the function that should be reviewed as well.

This code works, and gets a clean bill of health from [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void readAllLines(FILE *f, char ***res, int *num_read);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char **wordList = 0;
    FILE *fid;
    int numLines = 0;
    if (argc > 1 && (fid = fopen(argv[1], "r")) != 0)
    {
        readAllLines(fid, &wordList, &numLines);
        fclose(fid);
        for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
            printf("%d: %s", i, wordList[i]);
        for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
            free(wordList[i]);
        free(wordList);
    }
    return 0;
}

void readAllLines(FILE *f, char ***res, int *num_read)
{
    char buffer[128];
    int size;
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), f))
    {
        *num_read = *num_read + 1;
        size = strlen(buffer) + 1;
        char **space = (char **)realloc(*res, sizeof(char *) * (*num_read));
        if (space == 0)
            return;
        *res = space;
        (*res)[*num_read - 1] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
        if ((*res)[*num_read - 1] == 0)
            return;
        strcpy((*res)[*num_read - 1], buffer);
        printf("%s\n", (*res)[*num_read - 1]);
    }
    printf("%s\n", (*res)[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible reason for a segmentation fault:

```
 res = (char***)malloc(sizeof(char**));
 *res = (char **)realloc(*res,sizeof(char*)*(*num_read));
```

In the second line you try to reallocate whatever `*res` is pointing to. However since you did not initialize `*res` this could be anything. This will work only if `*res == NULL`. I guess it should be `malloc`, not `realloc`.

Other problems:

You allocate everything new in each loop iteration. This is a huge memory leak.

You already pass a valid memory address pointing to an `char**` by `res`, you shouldn't allocate for it again. It is an out parameter. (Remove the `malloc` call)

You need an initial `malloc` for `*res` before the loop (Or set `*res = NULL`).

The second `realloc` for `*res[...]` should be a `malloc`, because you never actually reallocate here. Also instead of allocating `size` bytes, you should allocate `size+1` bytes for the terminating `\0`.

Your function has no return statement although it is non-void.

Comment: But I need to increase the size of the array of pointers bc it is an array of strings.

Comment: do i need not set up **res for the character array?

Comment: @user3213348: That pair of lines is another problem.  Yet another problem is that you only allocate enough space for `size` characters, not `size+1`.  Always remember to account for the null byte at the end of a string; `strlen()` does not count that byte.